# sparkR: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sparkr

**I am struggling solving this problem when I try to use sparkR.**

```
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "1g"))
Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) : 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:981)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$$anonfun$setSparkContextSessionConf$2.apply(SQLUtils.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$$anonfun$setSparkContextSessionConf$2.apply(SQLUtils.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.Traversabl
```

Hope this is a clear solution, I am new to spark and I know nothing about java scala. THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Looks like it is related to user permissions. Therefore you've two options:

1) Launch sparkR from a directory, where you have the necessary rights (prerequisite: The spark bin folder needs to be included in the PATH env-variable: `export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH`):

```
cd ~
sparkR
```

2) Launch sparkR with sudo privileges:

```
/opt/spark/bin $ sudo ./sparkR
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try removing the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` from environment variables